# Observing an array that is initialised in the created lifecycle event

Tags: polymer

I have a working Polymer prototype, a code snippet of which is:

```
Polymer({
    myData: [],
    observe:{
        myData: 'myDataChange'
    },
    myDataChange: function(val, newVal){ ... }
    ...
```

However, under the the [attribute hinting section of the developer API](https://www.polymer-project.org/docs/polymer/polymer.html#attrhinting), it states that objects and arrays should be initialised in the created lifecycle callback, not on the prototype. So, I changed the code snippet above to:

```
Polymer({
    created: function(){
        this.myData = [];
    },
    observe:{
        myData: 'myDataChange'
    },
    myDataChange: function(val, newVal){ ... }
    ...
```

As soon as I make this change, the change watcher function no long invokes.

The myData property of my element instance is being populated by jQuery in an document ready callback. Moving this code into a 'polymer-ready' callback on the containing page solves this issue.

My concern with this is that my pages are going to be littered with polymer-ready events for the initial data population.

I amended my prototype so that the custom element is added to the DOM after a 5 second timeout, after the polymer-ready event was fired. Injecting the DOM like this doesn't fire the polymer ready event again.

Is this the correct/best approach to initialising properties on a Polymer element? I could manually fire an event from my custom element to say its loaded but this seems a bit crude. Any better ideas?

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't use any custom element before `polymer-ready` event (unless you're doing it intentionally), I think the best you could do is to replace every `ready` callback with `polymer-ready`.

However if you still want to use `ready` callback you could call `myDataChange` inside the element's `ready` callback:

```
Polymer({
    created: function(){
        this.myData = [];
    },
    observe:{
        myData: 'myDataChange'
    },
    ready: function() {
        this.myDataChange([], this.myData);
    },
    myDataChange: function(val, newVal){ ... }
    ....
```